# Does partner wsdl change between sandbox

Tags: integration, webservices, soap, partner-wsdl

I have provided a partner wsdl to an external system. This wsdl was extracted from DEV sandbox , now I am moving the code to another sandbox , do I need to generate the wsdl from that sanbox again or can I just ask the external system to change the end point? if end point, the where can I get the end point details for new sandbox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be used for any org.

> ## [Using the Partner WSDL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_partner.htm)
>
> As a loosely typed representation of the Salesforce data model that works with name-value pairs of field names and values instead of specific data types, **it can be used to access data within any organization**

Endpoint is returned as part of the login call.

Comment: Thanks!. I am looking at a sample call using Java - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_partner_examples.htm . Don't we need a end point information when making a login call? How does the external system knows which endpoint it is hitting? or is it same for all the sandbox?

Comment: either use test or login dot salesforce.com